# How to rank data on microsoft access

Tags: ms-access

On **Microsoft Access** i'd like to create a **Rank System** in a table based on the time of each participant.

For instance, if person A got 14:20 and person B got 12:40 and person C got 10:10. Person C would get 3 points, Person B would get 2 points and Person A would get 1 point.

**Ref:**

[image]

Comment: Something like this should work:
SELECT Scores.[Student], Scores.Duration, (select count(*) from YourTable where Scores.Duration>=Duration) AS Rank
FROM YourTable AS Scores
ORDER BY Scores.Duration ASC;